# User Permission - Only installing from Ubuntu Software Centre

Tags: permissions, software-center, user-management

My father in law's 14 month old Dell Computer's hard drive just crapped out, I replaced it with a new hard drive and since Dell won't send him a product key for the windows 8 that he purchased them I decided to try to install Ubuntu (14.10). Now what I would like to do is stop him from installing anything outside of the Ubuntu Software Centre. I think this is the best method for him installing software for his new operating system. If he needs something that isn't in the Ubuntu Software Centre, I can install at a later date using terminal.

Comment: Please clarify, what is your question?

Comment: iinm Reuben is asking how to block the installation of all packages except for the packages in the default Ubuntu repositories unless he authenticates the installation by using a different password that only he has.

Comment: @karel is correct - I would like to block my father in law's user account from installing anything unless it is through the Ubuntu Software Centre. I really don't care if he installs stuff but I want to stop him from installing things that haven't been compiled properly or scanned for viruses.